# Javascript Check if part of string is contained in enum values

Tags: javascript, typescript, enums

I have an enum

```
 enum YourEnum {
   enum1 = 'Sunday',
   enum2 = 'Monday',
   enum3 = 'Tuesday',
}
```

and I want to check if some part of word are included in. If for example user tips "mon", i'm expecting that it matches with Monday.

I have two problems: I need to convert values of enum in lowercase, and I need that part of word match.

I tried to do that:

```
var value = "mon";
if (Object.values(YourEnum).toString().toLowerCase().includes((value))) {
    console.log("some values match")
}
```

or

```
const list=Object.values(YourEnum).toString().toLowerCase();
for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
    if (list[i].indexOf("mon") >= 0){
        console.log("some values match", list[i]);
     }
}
```

But I don't get the results I'm expecting.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Do you need to convert them to lower case permanently or only for the search purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to find which item of the enum your search string is matching against? In that case try using the array `.find` method to check each enum member for a match, returning the first that does:

```js
/*
enum YourEnum {
   enum1 = 'Sunday',
   enum2 = 'Monday',
   enum3 = 'Tuesday',
}
*/

// This is how a typescript enum is transpiled, it is equivalent to the typescript code above.
var YourEnum;
(function(YourEnum) {
  YourEnum["enum1"] = "Sunday";
  YourEnum["enum2"] = "Monday";
  YourEnum["enum3"] = "Tuesday";
})(YourEnum || (YourEnum = {}));

// Here is an example of how it might be done.
const findMatchingDay = search_str =>
  Object.values(YourEnum).find(day => day.toLowerCase().includes(search_str));

console.log(findMatchingDay("mon"));
console.log(findMatchingDay("not_a_day"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const list=Object.values(YourEnum).toString().toLowerCase();
```

When you use above line of code its converting the list to a string

```
"sunday,monday,tuesday"
```

**You can use the below script to get expected results**

```
const list=Object.values(YourEnum);

for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
    if (list[i].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf("mon")>=0){
        console.log("some values match", list[i]);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will find the search by filtering the `enum` for lowercase versions of the enum. Note that StackSnippets doesn't like `enum` keyword due to babel, so had to include link to TS Playground snippet.

`Object.values` returns an array that you can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on to filter out everything that does not `contain` the test.

```
const test: string = 'mon';

enum YourEnum {
   enum1 = 'Sunday',
   enum2 = 'Monday',
   enum3 = 'Tuesday',
}

const out = Object.values(YourEnum).filter(value=>value.toLowerCase().includes(test));
console.log(out);
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCm0BcNoCcCWYDmMC8MA5ALbiEDcAsAFA3xgCuxMAmiA2gKKPMDeNMQfSYBGfEQDKDMABMAhgE9CAGgFCeAJnGEAsuHlLV1QTGHEAzNoAqDRAZU0AvjRqhIsdrAIB5AEYAreGAoADoANzkAG1sIAAo2Dm4mAEoQgDMMSIQ0WIjo+DwAPjzbEKgQABkQAHd4NABhOQh4WNSsYGiZRFiEaGTkqmo3CBBI+BDIkGxYzwGgA)